# Favorable wind control wind combo

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Could a character cast a favorable wind to create a 30 mph wind 60 ft. wide and then cast control wind to at 9 th level increase the wind speed to huricane force winds 360 ft long? Favorable Wind is page 113 Stormwrack, Control Wind page 214 Players Hand book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Other spells' areas are usually unchanged by [*control winds*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#control-winds)

The 3rd-level Drd spell and 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell *favorable wind* [conj] (*Stormwrack* 116-7) is an area spell that creates a 60-ft. cone that emanates from a grid intersection adjacent to the caster. The 5th-level Drd spell [*control winds*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#control-winds) (*Player's Handbook* 214) is also an area spell yet it creates a nonstandard 40-ft./level-radius effect that's 40-ft. high and that moves with the caster and that the caster can alter. Neither spell's area *changes* the other spell's area.

For example, a level 9 druid casts the spell *favorable wind* and creates a cone of [strong wind](http://dndsrd.net/wildernessAndEnvironment.html#winds). Then that same druid follows up the *favorable wind* spell with the spell *control winds*. Wind whipped up *outside* the *favorable wind* spell's area by the *control winds* spell is still limited in its shifts by the region's normal prevailing wind condition, like, for instance, from no wind through light wind through moderate winds to strong wind. However, the wind *inside* the *favorable wind* spell's cone—and *only* in that 60-ft. cone—can have its strength adjusted by the spell *control winds* from strong through severe through windstorm to hurricane.

In other words, when the *favorable wind* spell's wind strength is modified by the spell *control winds* cast by a level 9 caster, the typical result is usually only a maximum of a *60-ft. cone* of hurricane wind, *not* a *360-ft. cone* of hurricane wind.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, you can create a hurricane that way

### In short

1. *Favorable Wind* "produces a stream of wind" and "The wind force is **strong**, with a speed of about 30 mph." It specifies some differences from *normal* strong wind: it is a bit stronger against creatures, but limited in range.
2. *Control Winds* allows you to "alter wind force in the area surrounding you", "increase its strength" by one step per 3 caster levels (9 levels in your case, 3 steps).
3. Hence, you **can** use the latter to affect the former, making the "strong wind" into a hurricane.

### A bit longer

Favorable Wind spell (didn't find it in SRD, reprinting text from a book):

> **Level:** Druid 3, Sorcerer/Wizard 4
>
> **Components:** V, S
>
> **Casting Time:** 1 standard action
>
> **Range:** 60 ft
>
> **Area:** Cone-shaped emanation
>
> **Duration:** 10 min/level
>
> **Saving throw:** Fortitude negates
>
> **Spell Resistance:** no
>
> This spell **produces a stream of wind** that can fill a ship's sails, disperse vapors and gases, and keep flying creatures at bay. **The wind force is *strong*, with a speed of about 30 mph.** It begins where you stand and blows directly away from you; you can easily propel a sailing vessel by standing astern of the mast and directing the wind forward to fill the sails. Tiny or smaller creatures in the path of the wind are knocked prone, or of flying are blown back 1d6*10 feet. Small creatures are checked and cannot make headway against the wind. Small airborne creatures are instead blown back 1d6*5 feet. Medium and larger creatures can move normally within effect. A *favorable wind* can't push a creature beyond the limit of its range. Any creature, regardless of size, takes a -2 penalty on ranged attacks.

Quoting the description of ["Control Winds"](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/controlWinds.htm):

> You alter wind force in the area surrounding you. You can make the wind blow in a certain direction or manner, **increase its strength**, or decrease its strength. The new wind direction and strength persist until the spell ends or until you choose to alter your handiwork, which requires concentration.
>
> [...]
>
> **Wind Strength**
>
> For every three caster levels, you can increase or decrease wind strength by one level. Each round on your turn, a creature in the wind must make a Fortitude save or suffer the effect of being in the windy area.
>
> Strong winds (21+ mph) make sailing difficult.
>
> A severe wind (31+ mph) causes minor ship and building damage.
>
> A windstorm (51+ mph) drives most flying creatures from the skies, uproots small trees, knocks down light wooden structures, tears off roofs, and endangers ships.
>
> Hurricane force winds (75+ mph) destroy wooden buildings, sometimes uproot even large trees, and cause most ships to founder.
>
> A tornado (175+ mph) destroys all nonfortified buildings and often uproots large trees.

Then we have the [Weather](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/weather.htm) rules on d20srd.

> **Winds**
>
> The wind can create a stinging spray of sand or dust, fan a large fire, heel over a small boat, and blow gases or vapors away. If powerful enough, it can even knock characters down (see Table: Wind Effects), interfere with ranged attacks, or impose penalties on some skill checks.

In particular, we should look at the [Table: Wind Effects](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/weather.htm#tableWindEffects), where we see the "strong wind". Wind speed is listed as "21-30 mph", Ranged penalty as -2. There is also a Fortitude save difficulty listed as 10, but in our case substituded by caster's respective number.

Strong Wind entry in the text says:

> Strong Wind
>
> Gusts that automatically extinguish unprotected flames (candles, torches, and the like). Such gusts impose a -2 penalty on ranged attack rolls and on Listen checks.

### The spell has a range

I just noticed that you asked about the range of the wind. The *Favorable Wind* spell has a range of 60 ft., and explicitly says that "A favorable wind can't push a creature beyond the limit of its range."

You would not be able to push creatures that way, but *probably*, at GMs discretion you would be able to push something else, deny ranged attacks, etc.